# How can i find type of a surface(toponym) is that point?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a point with lat-long and i want to know what type surface(toponym) that point is: house, road, land etc. How can i do this with google api? I cant find solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Google maps API doesn't provide a solution for figuring that out.

Comment: You have to look at open data solutions, government data, and others. Way out of scope of mapping apis.